# October CMS | Dynamic importExportConfig in same controller

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I want to implement two different import procedure in same controller. As October CMS configuration I created two import_export config files and two different Import Model Class. But it always point the Initial config file model class which I defined in `public $importExportConfig = 'config_import_export.yaml';` controller property.

My implementation code is given bellow,

```
public $importExportConfig = 'config_import_export.yaml';

public function __construct()
{
...
}

public function import($context = null)
{
    $this->asExtension('ImportExportController')->setConfig('config_import_export.yaml');
    $this->asExtension('ImportExportController')->import($context);
}

public function system_import($context = null)
{
    $this->asExtension('ImportExportController')->setConfig('config_system_import_export.yaml');
    $this->asExtension('ImportExportController')->import($context);
    return $this->makePartial('system_import');
}
```

Code in config file,

```
import:
    title: 'Import Phone Numbers'
    modelClass: Bol\PhoneManager\Models\SimImport
    list: $/bol/phonemanager/models/sim/export_import_columns.yaml
    redirect: bol/phonemanager/sim/import
```

If I initially `public $importExportConfig = '';` make the property blank then its points the proper Model Class as config file but then throw an error like bellow,

[image]

I am trying to solve in many ways but I can't found any solution. If there any other solution please help.